# List<IJob>.AddRange(List<Job>) doesn't work

Tags: c#, generics

I discovered that a list of concrete objects cannot be added to a list of interface object.

```
public static void AddJob(List<IJob> masterJobs, List<Job> jobs)
{
    masterJobs.AddRange(jobs);  //fail to compile
}
```

Instead, one needs to use the following code:

```
public static void AddJob(List<IJob> masterJobs, List<Job> jobs)
{
    masterJobs.AddRange(jobs.Cast<IJob>());  
}
```

What is the rational behind this?

Comment: Skeet + covariance/contravariance in three... two... one...

Comment: Will work if you are able to use C# 4.0

Comment: I'm going to assume that the `//fail to compile` comment in the second example above is left-over from the first? Or does that too fail to compile?

Comment: @Lasse, yup, it's a left over and has been fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lasse is right about why this won't work in C# 3 - there is no conversion from `List<IJob>` to `List<Job>`.

In C# 4 it will work, not because of the *list* being covariant, but because `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant. So in other words, the code would effectively be:

```
public static void AddJob(List<IJob> masterJobs, List<Job> jobs)
{
    IEnumerable<IJob> jobsTmp = jobs; // This is the covariance working
    masterJobs.AddRange(jobs); // This is now fine
}
```

`jobs` implements `IEnumerable<Job>`, so there's a reference conversion to `IEnumerable<IJob>` through covariance, so it all works fine. The call to `Cast<T>` is effectively doing a similar job in your C# 3 workaround - you're using it to convert to an `IEnumerable<IJob>`.

If you want to more about generic variance, there's a [video of my NDC 2010 talk](https://web.archive.org/web/20101216073921/http://streaming.ndc2010.no:80/tcs/) available, or read Eric Lippert's [series of blog posts](https://ericlippert.com/category/covariance-and-contravariance/) on it.

Comment: So, let me get this straight... they used `in` and `out` to signify contra/covariance because it essentially describes that the class *only* "takes in" an instance of the generic type (i.e., a method argument) or if the class *only* "passes out" an instance of the class (i.e., return value of a method)?  IEnumerable<T> does not "take in" any T's, so it is safe to mark the class as <out T> and therefore the generic type is covariant?  IList<T> both takes in T and passes out T, which makes it invariant?

Comment: @Will: Yes, that's exactly right. See Eric Lippert's blog post series about variance for a lot more information. I'll edit my post to link to it.

Comment: By George, I think I's got it!  I think I's got it!  (cue musical number)

Answer (score 8):

The reason is that a `List<IJob>` is not a `List<Job>`, although a `Job` implements `IJob`.

This is co- or contra-variance (I never remember which is which.)

The thinking goes something like this:

The compiler cannot guarantee that `AddRange` only reads things out of the parameter it is given, and thus it cannot guarantee that this is safe, and thus it fails to compile.

For instance, for all the compiler knows, AddRange could add another object into the `jobs` parameter, that implements `IJob` (because AddRange expects `IJob` collections), but isn't `Job`, which is what `jobs` expect, and thus that would not be safe.

In C# 4.0, there is some support for handling this, but I'm not sure it would handle your particular case since the support has to be specified on the interface-level, and not at the method-level.

In other words, you would have to specify on the interface type that everything that relates to T is only going into the collection, never out of it, and then the compiler would allow you do this. However, a collection you cannot read from would be pretty pointless.

Comment: "out" is covariance and "in" is contravariance; its now `IList<out T>` and so is covariant. (and I'm wrong on that, see below)

Comment: Ooh, nice, don't think I've seen that short a summary of the two before, thanks!

Comment: This guy goes into good detail about covariance and contravariance generics support in 4.0:  http://www.buunguyen.net/blog/new-features-of-csharp-4.html

Comment: @Will: No, `IList<T>` is still invariant because it has values going both in and out. `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant though.

Comment: And now I know *why*.  Man, that's an awesome feeling when things all click into place.

Comment: @Will: Isn't it just? :) Quick now - should `Action<Action<Action<T>>>` be declared as covariant or contravariant? ;)

Comment: @jon I'd have to say contravariant.  What did I win?