# How to add items to an existing list using AddRange

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, addrange

Am trying to update records and save changes to the database and it seems as i can't because i cannot get my list. sorry if my question is not clear.

Let me know if there's other way i can do it.

```
List<ClaimHistoryModel.ClientLog> ClaimLogs = new    List<ClaimHistoryModel.ClientLog>();
using (SidDbContext db = new SidDbContext())
    {
        var oldClaim = db.Client.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ClaimId == clientModel.ClaimId);

        oldClaim.CellNumber = clientModel.CellNumber;

        ClaimLogs = GetClaimLog(db); //here am getting a method which update the Logtbl.(all the changes will be saved) no error on this funstion
      //it works if i save changes here but it won't update the history table which shows the fieds before and after.            
       db.claimAudit.AddRange(ClaimLogs ); Error here
       db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Am getting this error:

> Cannot convert from `System.Collections.Generic.List<ClaimHistoryModel.ClientLog>` to `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<claimAudit>`

Comment: The error seems pretty clear.  You're trying to add a collection of `MyModel` items to a list of `claimAudit` objects.

Comment: Mymodel != claimAudit. Unless `Mymodel` inherits `claimAudit`, this can't be done like this.

Comment: The OP did not say what the types were, MyModel and claimAudit didn't exist

Comment: I fixed the format, now you can see the different types...

Comment: Umm.  Where is `List<Mymodel>` come from?  I see `List<ClaimHistoryModel.ClientLog> ClaimLogs`.  Also, where does `IEnumerable<claimAudit>` come from?  There's nothing in the code presented that suggests that is what the types are.  Don't add information that isn't there if you are editing.

Comment: I am not sure on how i can fix this going forward. I just need a way to add to the list and save changes

Comment: What is the type of `claimAudit`?

Comment: @BerinLoritsch i didn't want to copy the whole the..but atleast you have all the info now

Comment: The main exception says, `You can't add Mymodel objects to a list of claimAudit`

Comment: public DbSet<ClaimAudit> claimAudit { get; set; }

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen  I looked at the original message, and the types **were not specified** in the error message.  Instead of adding what we assume are the types, we need to have the OP tell us exactly what they were.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List<IJob>.AddRange(List<Job>) Doesn't Work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343246/listijob-addrangelistjob-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

That will never work. You cannot add a `ClientLog` collection to a collection that expects `ClaimAudit`.That's the same as trying to add an object of type Order to a collection of objects of type User.I hope I'm making sense...

The example below will work because `db.claimAudit.AddRange()` expects two things:

1. An `IEnumerable`
2. An `IEnumerable` of type `ClaimAudit`

And `List<ClaimAudit>` satisfies both those conditions.As soon as you change `List<ClaimAudit>` to `List<ClientLog>` you are violating point 2 and the code will break

```
var claimAudits = new List<ClaimAudit>();
var claim1 = new ClaimAudit();
var claim2 = new ClaimAudit();
claimAudits.Add(claim1);
claimAudits.Add(claim2);

db.claimAudit.AddRange(claimAudits);
```

Maybe you actually need to insert claim logs instead of claim audits, if that's the case then just change this line:

```
db.claimAudit.AddRange(ClaimLogs);
```

to this:

```
db.claimLogs.AddRange(ClaimLogs);
```